# How to delete account in dynamics crm using c#?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

```
public void DeleteAccount()
{
    IOrganizationService service;
    Entity account = new Entity("account");
    Guid accountId = account.Id;
    **//accountId empty :(**

    service.Delete("account", accountId);
}
```

How to delete account in dynamics crm using c#? (I loaded list account using gridview, I don't get accountid)

Comment: Where is your code for the gridview?

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the account id by using the Retrieve multiple require or you need to hardcode the GUID to delete the record.

Above your code will always return empty GUID because you are creating a new object here.

Comment: IOrganizationService service;
    QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute();
            query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name");
            query.Attributes.AddRange("name");
            query.Values.AddRange("account"); 
            Entity accountEntity = 
           service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.FirstOrDefault();
            if (accountEntity != null)
                Guid accountID = accountEntity.Id;

Comment: Yes, this seems okay, but if this is a final code then still some corrections needed.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will search `Account` entity with name as `test account`, retrieve & then delete it. I assume you have initialized `IOrganizationService` with connection string to your CRM.

```
IOrganizationService service; //initialize this

QueryByAttribute query = new QueryByAttribute();
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name");
query.Attributes.AddRange("name");
query.Values.AddRange("test account"); 

Entity accountEntity = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.FirstOrDefault(); 

if (accountEntity != null) 
{
    Guid accountID = accountEntity.Id;
    service.Delete("account", accountID);
}
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/sample-retrieve-multiple-querybyattribute-class)